# azure python 'there's nothing here yet'

Tags: python, azure, web.py, kudu

I have a simple hello world website built in web.py in the file test.py

```
import web

urls = ("/.*", "hello")
app = web.application(urls, globals())

class hello:
    def GET(self):
        return 'Hello, world!'

def wsgiHandler(): 
    return web.application(urls, globals(), autoreload=False).wsgifunc()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

In azure website configuration i have:

1, turned on python 2.7.3

2, app settings PYTHONPATH to D:\home\site\wwwroot

3, app settings WSGI_HANDLER to test.wsgiHandler() This matches name of file to function in file.

4, added the handler mappings *, d:\Python27\python.exe, D:\python27\scripts\wfastcgi.py

I've saved and restarted the website but still see the azure landing page saying 'There's nothing here yet'. I've checked dir in the console and all my files are there (I use bitbucket continuous deployment). I can run it locally and it renders 'hello world' in the browser.

I have tried different default documents in azure configuration, currently just got 'index.html'.

I feel like I'm missing something small here but I have no idea why it isn't working?! Does the default document have to be specific, does the 'WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION' need changing?

**EDIT 23/10/14**

I've tried a hello world flask application and it is also not working. However I did notice the azure 'there's nothing here yet' landing page says 'This website is running Python 2.7.8'. This is different to the python version listed in azure websites config. Could this be related?

**EDIT 28/10/14 SOLVED**

I have solved this so here is the solution for others.

It seems azure was not updating web.config file based on the users inputs in the azure portal website configuration. So while my website configuration was as above, the web.config file still had the default WSGI_HANDLER as "hostingstart-oython.application" which meant it thought 'nothing was there'. Using Kudu helped, ie websitename.scm.azurewebsites.net